# http Post request And declaration of authorization header in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I am trying to perform an HTTP authorization using Ruby on Rails.  Here is what I'm trying:

```
res = http.post(uri.request_uri, 
:Authorization => cobSessionToken,
"coBrandSessionCredential=loginToken=#{cobSessionToken}&userLogin=#{login}&userPassword=#{password}")
render :json =>  {"isValid" => true, "Body" => JSON.parse(res.body)}
```

This doesn't seem to work.  How can I perform an authorization?

Comment: First, I made a few edits to your post.  Second, are you trying to perform an *authentication*?

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
url = URI.parse('https://my.url.com/path')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'
req.use_ssl = true
req.form_data({'key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2'})

resp = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(req) }
puts resp
```

Comment: A good idea here is to give a reference (link) to where OP can read and learn more about it. And maybe you could write a little bit about what is wrong with OPs code?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (its a free google program you can get at the google store) to make sure the error is not on the server side. Use Net:http it comes with ruby so you do not need to install it but you have to require it.
Require it by:

    `require "net/http"
    require "uri"`

Use this [cheatsheet](https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet) I think you need basic_auth.rb You will see how to form the request.